# PowerShell Remove-Item -Force does not remove non-owned directories imported from CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, directory, ownership

I'm pretty new to this and would appreciate any advice I can get.
I'm using PowerShell Version 5.1 and Ive been able to use the following code:

$dir = Import-Csv DirectoryList.csv
$dir | ForEach-Object {$_."Directory" | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse}

To remove a list of directories as specified in "DirectoryList.csv"; however, it does not remove folders for which I am not an owner of. Yes, I am admin on the box, and I know that doesn't translate to owner ;)

I'm sure there is a way I can ensure that for each directory listed in the CSV file for which a specific AD Administrators Group (ex:ArchiveAdministrators) is not the owner, it is changed to the owner, then deletes the folder and all it's contents, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I tried modifying the script to:

$dir = Import-Csv DirectoryList.csv
$dir | ForEach-Object {$_."Directory" | Set-NTFSOwner -account ArchiveAdministrators\tfl | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse}

Now when it runs, it does nothing, and I get this error:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`Set-NTFSOwner`](https://ntfssecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cmdlets/Set-NTFSOwner/) doesn't output a *directory*-information object, so you cannot pipe its output directly to `Remove-Item`; use two distinct statements:

```sh
Import-Csv DirectoryList.csv $dir | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Directory | Set-NTFSOwner -account ArchiveAdministrators\tfl
  if ($?) { $_ | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse }
}
```